# If $K$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ s. t. $B_r(\vec{x}) \cap K =\{\vec{x}\}$ then $K$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I was wondering if my proof is not wrong. I'd appreciate if it could be reviewed.

Prove: If $K$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\forall \vec{x}\in K$, $\exists r(\vec{x})$ such that $B_r(\vec{x}) \cap K =\{\vec{x}\}$, then $K$ is finite.

> **Proof:**
>
> We need to show that $K$ contains finitely many elements. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that, given $B_r(\vec{x}) \cap K =\{\vec{x}\}$, $K$ is not finite. Then $H:=\bigcup\limits_{\vec{x}\in K}B_r(\vec{x})$ is an infinite union of open balls. Choose $\|r(\vec{x})\|$ to be the minimum possible radius to satisfy the given condition, such that $H$ is an infinite union of disjoint open balls. We can observe that $H$ is an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover $L$ of $K$, such that $L\subset H$, and $L$ is a finite union of open sets. But $H$ has no possible proper subsets, thus $H$ is a finite union of open balls, which is a contradiction. Hence, $K$ is finite.

To be more precise, maybe I should state: $\forall \varepsilon >0$, let $0 < \|r(\vec{x})\| < \varepsilon$, so that $\|r(\vec{x})\| < \varepsilon$ is the minimum possible radius of $B_r(\vec{x})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, but there is a problem in your proof where you're choosing the minimum $\|r(x)\|$ among an infinite collection of radii. This minimum might not exist, and the infimum of the collection could be zero. Alternatively, just choose a finite subcover of $\{B_{r}(x)\}$ first, and notice that each of these balls intersected with $K$ is a singleton. But this covers $K$ and there are only finitely many of the balls. So our conclusion is?

Comment: Can you please clarify the following?
*
1. How could it be that the minimum does not exist? We could choose an infinitesimally small radius.
*
2. How could there be an infimum of a collection? Do you mean of the union? And how could there be that the infimum is zero, and how is it relevant to this proof?
*
3. Do you mean to choose a finite subcover of $\bigcup B_r(x)$? But how does this help? We're already given that the intersection of an open ball centered at $x$ is a singleton.

Comment: @sequence. 1. There is no such thing as infinitesimally small radius. 2. Infimum is defined for collections of real numbers, and the collection I'm referring to is the infimum of the radii which are reals. 3. This helps because if $\{B_{r_{i}}(x_{i})\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a cover of $K$ and $B_{r_{i}}(x_{i})\cap K=\{x_{i}\}$ for each $i=1,...,n$, then each ball covers only one point of $K$. There are finitely many balls, so this union covers only finitely many points of $K$. But it **is** a cover of $K$, so we have to conclude that $K$ has only finitely many points.

Comment: So we appreciate the fact that because $K$ is compact and an open cover of $K$ is $\bigcup B_r(x)$, and there exists a finite subcover of $K$, a finite subcover of $K$ must be a subset of a finite union of $\bigcup B_r(x)$?

Comment: @sequence. If $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ is any cover of $K$, then every subcover $\{U_{j}\}_{j\in J}$ automatically satisfies $$K\subseteq \bigcup_{j\in J}U_{j}\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}U_{i}.$$ The first inclusion comes from the word "cover" and the latter inclusion from the word "sub". The open cover here is $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ and not $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{i}$. The latter is just a superset of $K$. In our problem, the finite subcover is special because each member of the cover covers only one point of $K$. This means that we can cover $K$ by covering only finitely many of its points.

Comment: In the definition in my textbook it's said that a collection $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a cover of a set $E$ if and only if $E\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in A}$. So when we say $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a cover of $E$, that means that we're dealing with the union of members in the collection $\{V_{\alpha}\}$, correct?   @T.Eskin

Comment: @sequence. True, that is the definition. I don't know if I fully understand your question. By saying the word "cover" we already include the fact that $K$ is a subset of the union, by definition. So we don't necessarily have to write the union at any point during our argument if we use the term "cover".